# Apache Internal RE-WRITE to replace 301 redirect

Tags: apache-2.2, redhat, mod-rewrite

I need to internally rewrite (due to partial CMS content restructure) as I currently have a permanent 301 redirect and it is killing SEO. I do not want the users browser to redirect or know about the content location change.

**Case One**

```
www.example.com 
internally rewritten to 
www.example.com/home/home.html
```

**Case Two**

```
www.example.com/home.html 
internally rewritten to 
www.example.com/home/home.html
```

This is what I’ve writen to internally rewrite the path for case One:

```
RewriteRule ^/$ /home/home.html [NC,L]
```

The existing redirect rule (working fine) to be replaced is:

```
RewriteRule ^/$ http://www.example.com/home/home.html [R=301,L]
```

Any advice on where I’m going wrong welcome!